Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON received - Azure Devops - AWS CLI Task Definition
I'm facing a problem and I need help!
I have a release pipeline in Azure Devops with a task that should update the task definition of a specific service in ECS using a JSON file with the respective parameters that I extracted from the task definition itself that is already working. However, every time the pipeline is executed, it presents the error:
Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON received.
I tried to adjust the code several times but the error persists. Can you tell me what is wrong with this code?
Here's my code:
{
    "family": "especificfamilyname",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "especificname",
            "image": "especificimagefromecr",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "especificname",
                    "containerPort": 8000,
                    "hostPort": 8000,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "OPENAI_API_KEY",
                    "value": "especificvalue"
                }
            ],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "ulimits": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/",
                    "mode": "non-blocking",
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "max-buffer-size": "25m",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:especificarn",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:especificarn",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "volumes": [],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "1024",
    "memory": "3072",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    }
}


Hi, please check this same error question and its answer which may help you solve the issue.  By the way, can you please share the task details and the debug logs? You can enable the variable “system.debug”(set the value to “true”) in your pipeline, then trigger a new pipeline to get the debug log.
